# How to find linearised system using eigenvectors

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, manifolds, nonlinear-system

I have the system
\begin{align}
\frac{dx}{dt} &= y + x^2\\
\frac{dy}{dt} &= -y + x^2
\end{align}
with an equilibrium point at the origin

I've found the Jacobian matrix, and that

eigenvalue $1 = 0$

eigenvector $1 = (1, 0)$

eigenvalue $2 = -1$

eigenvector $2 = (1, -1)$

How do I find the linearised system from these eigenvectors? And how would I do it for general eigenvectors other than these ones? Thank you

Comment: Please use latex code

Comment: This question doesn't make any sense to me. If you know the Jacobian, you already know the linearized system! (But since zero is an eigenvalue, the origin is a non-hyperbolic equilibrium, so the linearization doesn't tell you much about the nonlinear system.)

Comment: @HansLundmark it seems common sense to you but I don't recall how to find the linearized system from the Jacobian lol, that is essentially my question. And thank you I have learned about non-hyperbolic stuff now

Comment: A linear system is one of the form $dx/dt=Ax$, where $A$ is a constant matrix and $x(t)$ is the vector of functions that you seek. And in this case, when you linearize at an equilibrium point, $A$ is just the Jacobian matrix evaluated at that point. It's as simple as that!